# Creating Alert Dialog object

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I understand how to create an AlertDialog object and how to add elements, but i can't understant what is getActivity() method, and how can i get it?

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should read [`getActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29) from documentation.

`getActivity()` can be used in `Fragments` and it returns :

> Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.

This method is created to get the current `Activity`

**Why you need it to create a dialog?**

As you can see the constructor of [`AlertDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#AlertDialog.Builder(android.content.Context)) requires a `context` then you have to pass the `getActivity()`

> But why am i getting "The name "getActivity" does not exist in the current context"?

If you are not in a `Fragment` you don't have to call `getActivity()` you can use `this` to pass the `context` of its `Activity`

### Example

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Comment: But why am i getting
    
        "The name "getActivity" does not exist in the current context"?

Comment: Maybe vecause you are not on a `Fragment` use `this` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `AlertDialog.Builder` constructor is looking for a [context](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.Context/) so in Xamarin you can pass it `this` for the current activity assuming you are already within an `Activity`.

```
var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.SetTitle("My Custom Alert").SetMessage("StackOverflow").Create().Show();
```

[image]